# Extracting unique colors of an overlay AxesImage in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, colors, renderer

This is a question about color information in matplotlib images.

I plot two arrays with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M1 = ([1,      2,      3,      np.nan], 
      [4,      5,      np.nan, np.nan], 
      [6,      7,      8,      9])

M2 = ([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, 1,      2,      3], 
      [np.nan, 4,      5,      6])

M1arr = ~np.isnan(M1)
M2arr = ~np.isnan(M2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im1 = ax.imshow(M1arr, cmap="Reds",  alpha=0.5)
im2 = ax.imshow(M2arr, cmap="Blues", alpha=0.5)

#color_array = mystery_function(im1, im2, ax, fig) 

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: ![![enter image description here]

Is there a way to extract the colors from the plotted compound image that we finally see (to create a colorbar, for instance)? I have seen this [amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794540/8881141) of how to reverse-engineer the colors from `im1` or `im2`. BUT `im2` is not the compound overlay image that we will finally see, `im1` and `im2` are seemingly only combined by `plt.show()`. I also tried to force matplotlib to pre-emptively generate the final image with `plt.draw()` and extract the image with `ax.get_images()`, alas the two images were still separated.

I am not interested in how to solve this differently - after useless attempts, I changed my strategy and [plotted the combined matrix instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65071780/8881141). My question is specifically, if we can extract the four colors from the `AxesImage` shortly before it is displayed.
Equally helpful would be information on how matplotlib combines the colours in the overlay. I tried summation of the colours in `im1` and `im2` (obviously wrong, because it can exceed 1) and mean value of each color channel (also wrong).

Comment: Ah yes, the strange behaviour of matplotlib's alpha compositing raises its ugly head again :-) Possibly related / informative discussions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089068/how-does-imshow-handle-the-alpha-channel-with-an-m-x-n-x-4-input) [2](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9906) [3](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/goerz/d6543e0878c1a10ed0da) [4](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colors.html).

Comment: Note that from my experience, the blending also depends on the backend (and also whether you save as `.png` or `.pdf`). Using `mixed_layer = (lower_layer * (1 - alpha) + higher_layer * alpha)` (as stated in link [4] above) with both the background layer (!!) and the two imshows _comes close_, but is still giving me slightly different colours as a result.

Comment: Somebody finally found the way to this question. *sob* Actually, I don't mind that the colors differ between backends, as long as I can reproduce them within the same image for a colorbar or similar.

Comment: The thing is that you'll unfortunately still have to fiddle around, doing trial an error, to verify that this works _even within the same figure_. Since I couldn't figure out how each backend+output combination works, I'd rather suggest you create your own colormaps and blend by hand. It's much safer this way.

Comment: This is what I did in the end but I still find it strange that I neither was able to find an established way to access the overlay image before it was actually generated nor a description of the color mixing algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found the answer of how to get the rendered array. It is based on drawing the figure, as I tried before, and retrieving a memoryview of the renderer's buffer with [`fig.canvas.buffer_rgba()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/backend_agg_api.html?highlight=buffer_rgba#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.buffer_rgba):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

M1 = ([1,      2,      3,      np.nan], 
      [4,      5,      np.nan, np.nan], 
      [6,      7,      8,      9])

M2 = ([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, 1,      2,      3], 
      [np.nan, 4,      5,      6])

M1arr = ~np.isnan(M1)
M2arr = ~np.isnan(M2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(M1arr, cmap="Reds",  alpha=0.5)
ax.imshow(M2arr, cmap="Blues", alpha=0.5)


#get image without axis, so only the colors plotted in the overlay image are considered
ax.axis("off")
#get rgba values from image predrawn by the renderer
fig.canvas.draw()
im = fig.canvas.buffer_rgba()
#identify unique colors, containing white background
all_colors = np.unique(np.asarray(im).reshape(-1, 4), axis=0)
#remove white background color
colors_image = all_colors[:-1].reshape(4, -1)

#turn axes back on
ax.axis("on")
#determine cmap and norm for colorbar
cmapM1M2 = colors.ListedColormap(colors_image[::-1]/255)
normM1M2 = colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(-0.5,4), 4) 

#temporarily draw image of zeroes to get scalar mappable for colorbar
temp_im = ax.imshow(np.zeros(M1arr.shape), cmap=cmapM1M2, norm=normM1M2)
cbt = plt.colorbar(temp_im, ticks=np.arange(4), fraction=0.035)
#and remove this temporary image
temp_im.remove()

#label colorbar
cbt.ax.set_yticklabels(["M1 & M2 NaN", "only M1 values", "only M2 values", "M1 & M2 values"])
#and overlay image
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(M1arr.shape[1]))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(M1arr.shape[0]))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

To use the identified unique colors in a colorbar, I draw a temporary image that later is removed. One could also draw a colorbar from scratch instead but it turned out rather annoying to control all parameters for this by hand.

*Update*
I just noticed that a colorbar is not required, it was just convenient in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65071780/8881141). So, we could alternatively just create a figure legend with patches:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

M1 = ([1,      2,      3,      np.nan], 
      [4,      5,      np.nan, np.nan], 
      [6,      7,      8,      9])

M2 = ([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, 1,      2,      3], 
      [np.nan, 4,      5,      6])

M1arr = ~np.isnan(M1)
M2arr = ~np.isnan(M2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(M1arr, cmap="Reds",  alpha=0.5)
ax.imshow(M2arr, cmap="Blues", alpha=0.5)

#after this, I want to extract the colors of the overlay image

#get image without axis, so only the colors plotted in the overlay image are considered
ax.axis("off")
#get rgba values from image predrawn by the renderer
fig.canvas.draw()
im = fig.canvas.buffer_rgba()
#identify unique colors, containing white background
all_colors = np.unique(np.asarray(im).reshape(-1, 4), axis=0)
#remove white background color
colors_image = all_colors[:-1].reshape(4, -1)


#turn axes back on
ax.axis("on")
#and overlay image
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(M1arr.shape[1]))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(M1arr.shape[0]))

#create legend with patches of the four colors
categories = ["M1 & M2 NaN", "only M1 values", "only M2 values", "M1 & M2 values"]
fig.legend(handles=[mpatches.Patch(facecolor=col, edgecolor="k", label=categories[3-i]) for i, col in enumerate(colors_image/255)],
           loc="upper center", ncol = 2)

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Take home message: It is easier to [define parameters before plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65071780/8881141) than extracting information retrospectively from the backend's memory.