# How to define a color in matplotlib with combination of different percentage of different colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a series of data and for each of them, I would like to plot a line with matplotlib. And I want to define a color for each condition by a combination of two different colors in order to distinguish them but with gradually changing colors.
For example, I would like to define a color like `m% * blue + n% * red`, where m and n could be 10%, 20%, 30%, etc., something like the way to define a customized color in LaTex, but I could not find anything by search on the manual or internet. Could you please tell me how to do that?

My original data is large, in order to keep the question simple, I guess maybe I could use the following data as a minimum example. For example, the first line is in color `20%*blue+20 %*red` and the second line could be in color `50%*blue+40 %*red` or any combinations are good. I think the main aspect of the problem is kept.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

x1 = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y1 = np.random.rand(10)
x2 = np.linspace(1, 10, 20)
y2 = np.random.rand(20)

plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
```

Comment: Yes you can do it. Provide a reproducible example of you dateset and I'll show you how

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! My original data is too large, I guess maybe I could use two simple lines for example. I modified my original post. If you think the data is a good minimum example, could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Are these colors restricted to red and blue or can they be any colors defined by matplotlib like `gold` or `lime`? And what does 20% red and 20% blue mean for you? A faint red-blueish color?

Comment: @Mr.T Hi, I used red and blue just because they are simple. The hope is that it can work for any arbitrary combination of colors. I am using this because for example, with the water increase, I want the color to turn bluer. And I know Latex has such simple way to define a color.

Comment: Defining colors is easy, as matplotlib accepts RGB and RGBA values. Mixing colors is not easy - it is not simply 20% red channel from color 1 plus 40% red channel from color 2.

Comment: @Mr.T Sorry, I do not much about the fundamentals of the way to define the color in Latex. But I feel it is easy to use and maybe also intuitive to understand. I thought the mixed color should also has an RGB value for it. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to `plt.plot` function a parameter color as rgb value as `color=(r,g,b)`, where `r`, `g`, `b` are float in `[0,1]` representing the percentage of red, green and blue. I wrote some example code:

```
def myfunction(x, a=1):
    return np.sin(x+a)

x = np.linspace(-10,10,101)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for a in np.linspace(0,2,21):
    plt.plot(x, myfunction(x,a), color=(a/2, 1-a/2,0))
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

in this example i use the parameter `a` to change the red and green color of the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Color mixing is non-trivial, even if we extract the RGBA values of [defined colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html) with `to_rgba()`. However, we can cheat and let matplotlib do the calculations by plotting the same curve twice - first with `x%` `x_color` (`x%` represented as a value between 0 and 1 with 1 meaning 100%), then again with `y%` `y_color`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x_color = "orange"
y_color = "orchid"
for x in np.linspace(0, 1, 5):
    for y in np.linspace(0, 1, 4):
        ax.plot((x, x+0.1), (y, y), color=x_color, alpha=x) 
        ax.plot((x, x+0.1), (y, y), color=y_color, alpha=y)      

ax.set_xlabel(f"color {x_color}")
ax.set_ylabel(f"color {y_color}")
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Hello, this looks very nice. The alpha also plays a role here. Could you please tell me what is the difference between the color got in your way and got from the way of using RGBA?

Comment: You don't get the color value, just the overlay. I tried for a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65148129/8881141) to find out how matplotlib mixes colors, and it was torturous. Of course, each color has an RGBA value that you can [extract with matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html?highlight=to_rgba#matplotlib.colors.to_rgba), and so has the mixed color. But the relationship in each channel is non-linear, and it is not simply the arithmetic mean of the color channels.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers and explanations! Very helpful.